# Elegant way of setting headers in Play Framework 2.4.x

Tags: playframework, annotations, http-headers, playframework-2.0

Is there a more elegant way to set the `Content-Range`, `X-Content-Range` and `Content-Length` headers in Play Framework 2.4.x?

```
public static Result stream(Long id) {
    byte[] data = Song.get(id).getData();
    RangeWrapper range = new RangeWrapper(request().getHeader("Range"), data.length);

    Chunks<byte[]> chunks = ByteChunks.whenReady(out -> {
        out.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, range.getFrom(), range.getTo()));
        out.close();
    });

    // Is there a way of saying @After(range.getFrom(), range.getTo(), range.getContentLength(), data.length)?
    response().setHeader("Content-Range", String.format("bytes %d-%d/%d", range.getFrom(), range.getTo(), data.length));
    response().setHeader("X-Content-Length", Integer.toString(range.getContentLength()));
    response().setHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(range.getContentLength()));

    return status(206, chunks);
}
```

Or am I stuck with the solution presented because you cannot specify parameters with `@With`, `@Before` and `@After`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from putting the `setHeader(...)` methods in a utility method and calling it from each action to reduce code duplication, there is not much to improve on your solution (sadly).

Both action composition and global intercepts only work well for a `@Before` type case, especially if you want to pass on variables from the action they are quite useless.

Answer (score 1):

`@Before` and `@After` annotations were available in Play 1.x and they doesn't exists in Play 2.x anymore, you can use still `@With` with which you can incorporate your own class as interceptor for the controllers and/or actions.

Anyway I can't see nothing wrong in using `setHeader(...)` method within each action especially when they're depended on required resource's properties - like in chunked response.